# PAMI can't find class

Tags: php, debian, asterisk, asteriskami

I'm trying to install [PAMI library](https://github.com/marcelog/PAMI)
I installed it via pear:

```
# pear channel-discover pear.marcelog.name
# pear install marcelog/PAMI
```

and trying to use example.php

```
    $pamiClientOptions = array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'scheme' => 'tcp://',
        'port' => 9999,
        'username' => 'admin',
        'secret' => 'mysecret',
        'connect_timeout' => 10000,
        'read_timeout' => 10000
    );

    use PAMI\Client\Impl\ClientImpl as PamiClient;
    $pamiClient = new PamiClient($pamiClientOptions);

    // Open the connection
    $pamiClient->open();

    // Close the connection

$pamiClient->close();
```

when I try to use this script I receive error:

```
Class 'PAMI\Client\Impl\ClientImpl' not found
```

It's first time, I see that classes are included like this (use).
I'm using debian Linux also. Please, help.

**UPDATE**
Also it's installed in /usr/share/php/PAMI/

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I've found solution in ["in_depth explanation"](http://marcelog.github.io/articles/pami_introduction_tutorial_how_to_install.html)
You had to do this after pear installation

```
require_once '/usr/share/php/PAMI/Autoloader/Autoloader.php';
PAMI\Autoloader\Autoloader::register();
```

I put this two strings at top of my script and it works now. But it also receives strange

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Logger' not found in
```

I solve this by installing log4php:

```
$ pear channel-discover pear.apache.org/log4php
$ pear install pear.apache.org/log4php/Apache_log4php-2.1.0
```

And also you should put before first require_once -

```
require_once '/usr/share/php/log4php/Logger.php';
```